# wordpress WPML advanced fields relationship

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

i'm making a multilanguage website which uses the advanced custom fields relationship plugin. I'm reading out employers and if i read em out in the site's native language i have zero problems, however when i try to read them out in another language i get back a empty array. 
Do any of you guys know what i can do?

```
<?php
    $field = get_post_meta( get_the_id() );
    $posts = get_field('field_81');
    echo '<!--';
        echo 'test ';
        var_dump( $field );
        var_dump( $posts );
    echo '-->';
?>

<?php
    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'):
?>

<?php
    $fields = $field['medewerkers'];
?>

<?php
    $posts = $fields;
?>

<?php
    endif;
?>  

<?php
   if ($posts):
?>

<?php
       if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'nl'):
?>
           <h3 class="titelmedewerkers">Medewerkers</h3>    
           <?php
                elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'):
           ?>
           <h3 class="titelmedewerkers">Employees</h3>
           <?php
                elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr'):
           ?>
           <h3 class="titelmedewerkers">Employes</h3>   
           <?php
                else:
           ?>
            <h3 class="titelmedewerkers">Medewerkers</h3>   
           <?php
                endif;
           ?>       
            <ul class="medewerkers">
            <?php
                       foreach ($posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) 
                    ?>
            <?php
                          setup_postdata($post);
                    ?>
                  <li class="shadow">
                <strong><?php
                                 the_title();
                            ?></strong><br />
                <?php
                                 if (get_field('foto')):
                            ?>
                <?php
                                    $attachment_id = get_field('foto');
                                    $size          = "medium";
                                    $image         = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php  the_title(); ?>" /><br />
                <?php
                                 endif;
                             ?>
                <?php
                                 if (get_field('afdeling')):
                            ?>
                <?php
                                    the_field('afdeling');
                            ?><br />
                <?php
                                    endif;
                            ?>
                <?php
                                    if (get_field('titel')):
                            ?>
                    <?php
                                    the_field('titel');
                            ?><br />
                <?php
                                    endif;
                            ?>
                <?php
                                    if (get_field('tel')):
                            ?>
             <a href="tel:<?php the_field('tel'); ?>"><?php the_field('tel'); ?></a><br />
                <?php
                     endif;
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php
                endforeach;
            ?>
    <?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    </ul> 
<?php
    endif;
?>
<?php
      wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: $posts var is serializaed, try [unserialize($posts)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php) before

Comment: why so many opening and closing php tags?

Answer (score 0):

this part:

```
<?php
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'):
?>
<?php
 $fields = $field['medewerkers'];
?>
<?php
 $posts = $fields;
?>
        <?php
endif;
?>
```

creates $post only when `en`, not surprising that you don't have it in other languages

Comment: i know that, thats what i'm trying to do, it's not showing i english, only in dutch

Comment: so if you are using not dutch `var_dump( $field );` and `var_dump( $posts );` return empty arrays?